# Multiple languages support for WindowsFormApplication UserInterface?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have implemented one windows form application,In this application contains more user inputs to the application.So Currently in design i am using English as default language..So now i want to give a multi-language support options to the User..so In how can we implement this in windows Form Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use standard microsoft feature, called [satellite assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Simply set form `Localizible = true` and translate it into different languages by setting `Language = FR` (to example into French). IDE will create multiple resources and you will see each language as a folder near exe-file. To switch language - switch current culture and then load/reload form (by calling it's constructor):

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr");
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.ShowDialog();
```

Another way is to use something ready made (sorry, don't use them).

And last possibility is to implement own localization. To example, by using reflection and custom translation tables. This way it is possible to switch languages *on a fly*, build translation into the software or create own tools to maintain translation. In past, I had tools to generate a text file from resources and then back, to be able to send file for translation to someone.

Step by step guide:

- create new winform application,
- add `label1` to the `form1`,
- set `form1.Localizable=true`,
- select `form1.Language = fr` and change `label1.Text=FR`,
- reset `form1.Language` with right click (so you should see again `label1.Text=label1`),
- start application, you will see `form1` with "label1" text on it,
- now go to Program.cs:

  ```
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      // add this line
      System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr");
      Application.Run(new Form1());
  ```
- start application again, you will see `form` with "FR" text on it.

Comment: Hi..I tried about sample code..But it's not working...!

Comment: Added working guide to the answer, tell me what is not working.

Comment: ok...Thnx... It's Working Now :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy all files to your local hard drive by means of the Copy All Files link.
2. Open the solution VBMultilingualForm.sln.
3. On the Build menu, click Build Solution.
4. On the Debug menu, click Start Without Debugging.
5. To see a different culture's resources, type a valid RFC 1766 culture name into the text box and click the switch button. A list of available cultures will appear when the mouse pointer hovers over the text box.

Link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289763%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Hi..Which files(means u told Copy All Files link) i needs to Copy?

Comment: k..but i didn't found that Solution file in my system :(