# Best Approach for Localisation variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I read more articles related to localization best practices. From them we can identigy that always UTCtime is best for handling date time. Like that we have some guidence like concetenation of string, ui etc.

But i also found one article saying we need to handle string / integer conversion. I din't get it properly. The following is the explanation

"Be sure to always pass CultureInfo when calling ToString() unless it is not supported. That way you are commenting your intents. For example: if you are using some number internally and for some reason need to convert it to string use:

```
int i = 42;
var s = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For numbers that are going to be displayed to user use:

```
var s = i.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); // formatting culture used
```

The same applies to Parse(), TryParse() and even ParseExact() - some nasty bugs could be introduced without proper use of CultureInfo. That is because some poor soul in Microsoft, full of good intentions decided that it is a good idea to treat CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as default one (it would be used if you don't pass anything) - after all when somebody is using ToString() he/she want to display it to user, right? Turn out it is not always the case - for example try to store your application version number in database and then convert it to instance of Version class. Good luck.
"

But why this is needed. So in all datatatypes we need to convert / do like this? what is the advatages for this as i got same result as with out adding culture info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do like this

```
double i = 42.42;
var s = i.ToString();
```

and run it on your on `English` PC (US or UK locale), then `s` will be

```
42.42
```

Now run it on `German` or `Russian` PC and suddenly `s` become

```
42,42
```

This different decimal point could lead to countless bugs in many places (when you save/load data, when you show values and reading user inputs, etc).

One possible ultimate solution, if your software will run on different locales, is to use `ColtureInfo.InvariantCulture` always when you `operate` with data and only when require user interruction `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

With `int` values problem could be with thousands separator (it could be missing, space, comma, point, etc).

I myself create extension methods, something like:

```
    public static string F(this string @this, params object[] args)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @this, args);
    }
```

so that i just write

```
"{0} {1:0.#}".F(Msg.Localization.User.Prompt, i);
```

where `Msg` is a localized messages class.

Comment: great. Likewise what are the special considertion needed for localization?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20259470/1997232) could be the most basic localization. But I myself prefer reflection to translate UI on-the-fly. To ease messaging (showing localized messages or dynamic text for controls), reflection is also the best, just create a class, holding `static string` entries of messages (spread in subclasses to ease referencing) in *default* (normally english) language. When language is changed, populate that class with *translation* (loaded from either satellite assemblies, which I hate, or special language files, containing edit-friendly localization).

Comment: ys i used seperate class library project and call the satellite assembly using reflection. File based resurce manager. Here we discussed the culture specific process like datatime handling, variables etc. Likewise any other process to consider?

Comment: Consider translation process itself, there are many approaches. Which I found the best is to update translation via language files (text files). If you load it when language is switched, then you have very fast way to check translation or update it and see results instantly. If you are using satellites then sorry =D